# Sending params while page pop ionic 4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

In Ionic 4 when I go from 1st to 2nd page with params:

```
let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      state: {
        param: 'param1'
      }
    };
    this.router.navigateByUrl(this.router.routerState.snapshot.url + '/page', navigationExtras);
```

I use the above code and retrieve this data

```
this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state;
```

by the above line but I also need to pass param when I go back from 2nd to 1st.

in Ionic 3 there is

`this.navCtrl.getPrevious().data.param= this.param;`

but I was not able to do this in ionic 4. can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Either use a service to set and retrive data from, or open the secons page as modal and on modal open send componentprops and set in modal close on method .dismiss(data to be sent back) and add on first page on modal dismiss subscription to get data back. These are 2 easy ways you can do.

Comment: Does that means there is no option like ionic 3 to send data to the previous page?

Comment: No there is no option like ionic 3 , and there is a third way to do that using observables so you fire observable on 2nd page leave and subscribe to observable on 1st page and get the params.

Comment: So can you share how exactly you navigate back to page 1? plz share code you use today and how ideally you wanted to pass params back t previous page.

Comment: `this.navCtrl.push(pageName, {params});` for goto 2nd page 


`ionViewWillLeave(){
   this.navCtrl.getPrevious().data.param= this.param;
 }`


while going back so I can use this data in 1st page like 


`if (this.navParams.data.param) this.param = this.navParams.data.param`

I want to same thing in ionic 4 as well.